# VPN failed for openconnect server

Tags: release-loki, vpn

Starting today after regularly using VPN using Loki's built-in nav-bar gui, I can't connect.  When I attempt to select the VPN service, it shows as an exclamation mark in a red circle.  Tooltip shows message "The Virtual Private Network could not be connected to."

[image]

I was able to successfully connect via the command line however (using openconnect directly) so it must be something wrong with the GUI?  Any suggestions as to what has happened?

I checked /var/log/syslog, grepping for both NetworkManager and openconnect and didn't find anything useful.  There were no hits for "openconnect" at all.